# Default Display Name As Username

Tags: customization, username

I don't know why it's so hard to find a solution for this but nothing seems to work when i finally find an answer..

I want to simply make the default display name as the users login/username..

I know I can edit each user, but I want it to be set like that for everyone and everyone that registers in the future.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: From a security point of view this might not the best idea as it could expose the usernames on the site and make brute forcing passwords a bit easier

Comment: I understand this and am aware. We are a small group of people on a private site so it's not a concern. Thanks

Comment: How is the author info displayed in your templates? What is so specific about the display name? Please list all the info that users are entering and data samples with an [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Set new user's display name as their login.
 * 
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/138034/1685
 * 
 * @param int $user_id
 */
function wpse_138034_display_name_as_login( $user_id ) {
    if ( $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ) ) {
        // Prevent infinite loop.
        remove_action( 'user_register', __function__ );

        wp_update_user(
            array(
                'ID' => $user_id,
                'display_name' => $user->user_login,
            )
        );

        // All done, restore.
        add_action( 'user_register', __function__ );
    }
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse_138034_display_name_as_login' );
```